# After changing Application_name Class not Found Exception occurs in android?

Tags: android, exception, android-manifest, classnotfoundexception

The Previous Application is 1.0.0 and In current application the version name changed from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 also changed the app_name in AndroidManifest.xml. After that exported the signed Application APK and try to re-install new APK but got following Exceptions.

Here is my Log error :

```
java.lang.RunTimeException: Unable to instantiate application [packageName] : 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : Didn't find the class android:name [ packageName :activityName]  on path :DexPathList  and Caused by :
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : Didn't find the the class.
```

Help me and suggest me why these happened ?

Comment: Post manifest.xml file..

Comment: First uninstall the current app, then try to install your app

Answer (score 0):

Remove your application from device and try again.

Hope it will help you.